# Changing the domain name in WP multisite - multidomain portal

Tags: wordpress

I changed the domain to a site on my word press 3.7 multisite (subdirectory) multidomain installation.
All wents fine but I cannot login anymore as superadmin to the domain changed site.
Also if I pass from the supersite to the domain name changed site, the portal ask again for credentials and doesn't recognise me.
In the supersite I changed the setting in the following areas: setting domain, domain mapping, sites.

Any tips?
Thanks

Comment: MAybe try to delete / regenerate the .htaccess ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED!
I changed back the site to the original domain name, later I added in Admin->domain the new domain using the same site id and setting it as primary site.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your database to point to the new domain. And make the following changes in your wp-config.php

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.newdomain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
```

In MySQL

```
update wp_options set option_value = "http://www.newsite.com/"  where option_id = 1;

update wp_options set option_value = "http://www.newsite.com/"  where option_id = 2;

update wp_blogs set domain = "www.newsite.com" where site_id = 1;

update wp_sitemeta set meta_value = "http://www.newsite.com/" where meta_id = 14;
```

Note: These settings in MySQL might change a little bit, so just confirm by doing a select on the table you're updating once. Mostly the structure should remain the same.